I get a compilation error for my vhdl code while using ghdl on linux mint
I am trying to learn vhdl therefore I am very new to the concepts of vhdl. I am on a linux mint machine and I am using ghdl and gtkwawe to compile my code. Currently I am trying to write a majority vote circuit with 4 inputs and 1 output. I have written a vhdl code and a testbench code for that but when I try to compile my testbench code I get a compilation error.
ghdl -a majority_voter.vhdl  
ghdl -a majority_voter_tb.vhdl  
error: cannot open majority_voter_tb.vhdl
/usr/bin/ghdl-gcc:error: compilation error

my majority_voter.vhdl code is:

entity majority_voter is
    port(a,b,c,d : in bit ; y : out bit);
end majority_voter ;

architecture vote of majority_voter is
begin
    y <=    (a and b and c and d) or 
            (c and d and ((not a and b) or (a and not b) )) or 
            (a and b and ((not c and b)or(c and not b) ));
end vote;

and my majority_voter_tb.vhdl code is:
entity majority_voter_tb is
end majority_voter_tb;

architecture vote of majority_voter_tb is

    component majority_voter
        port(a,b,c,d : in bit ; y : out bit);
    end component;

    for m_voter0 : majority_voter use entity work.majority_voter;
    signal a,b,c,d,y : bit;
begin
    m_voter0 : majority_voter port map (a => a,b => b,c => c,d => d,y => y  );
    
    process
    
        type pattern_type is record
            a,b,c,d : bit;
            y:bit;
        end record;
    
        type pattern_array is array (natural range <>) of pattern_type;
        constant patterns : pattern_array :=

            (('0', '0', '0', '0', '0'),
             ('0', '0', '0', '1', '0'),
             ('0', '0', '1', '0', '0'),
             ('0', '0', '1', '1', '0'),
             ('0', '1', '0', '0', '0'),
             ('0', '1', '0', '1', '0'),
             ('0', '1', '1', '0', '0'),
             ('0', '1', '1', '1', '1'),
             ('1', '0', '0', '0', '0'),
             ('1', '0', '0', '1', '0'),
             ('1', '0', '1', '0', '0'),
             ('1', '0', '1', '1', '1'),
             ('1', '1', '0', '0', '0'),
             ('1', '1', '0', '1', '1'),
             ('1', '1', '1', '0', '1'),
             ('1', '1', '1', '1', '1'));  
    begin

        for i in patterns' range loop
            a <= patterns(i).a;
            b <= patterns(i).b;
            c <= patterns(i).c;
            d <= patterns(i).d;
            wait for 1 ns;
            assert y = patterns(i).y
                report "voting error" severity error;

        end loop;
        assert false report "end of test" severity note;
        wait;
    end process;
end vote;
        


This appears to be tool usage and not a programming question. ghdl expects a target file be found in the directory it’s invoked in unless a file path is presented. The usual permissions issues may apply.

Check the path and the file name, especially for upper/lower case and typos.

Your test bench simulates when operating ghdl correctly with two assertion errors at 13 ns and 15 ns representing the 12th and 14th patterns values . There appears to be an and term error in your y and or. A VHDL design file can contain one or more design units (primary and secondary design units). You could place the test bench in the same file with entity majority_voter and it's architecture. The last y and term should use d instead of b (a and b and ((not c and d) or (c and not d) )); That'd be a typo or thinko.
